# Why do equal-duration d3 transitions get out-of-sync?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/benshope/bbbefc9dbd553141649b) is a simple bl.ock demonstrating the problem.

In this animation, the line's transition has the same duration as the circle's transition.  Despite their equal durations, the line's tip appears to move faster than the circle over the course of the 20-second animation.

The screenshot shows the effect at the beginning (left) and the end of the transition (right), respectively.

[image]

Why do these two transitions get out-of-sync?

Comment: strange i am using chrome/ff and it seems to be working as expected..both line and circle moving in sync...can you post a screen shot of what you seeing.

Comment: Things get even [more surprising](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/5c7bc79b4aee2b977c35) when adding a static line at `width/2`! I combined all transitions into one tween function to avoid synchronization issues but that's not the real issue. At first, I thought that the linear motion of the background compared to the non-linear motion of the line would cause this effect. On the other hand both, the line and the circle, are calculated equally based on the path's coordinates at a given length. Still not sure... @Cyril

Comment: When [using a linear data generator](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/6368d52abd896ce283c8) like `var randomNumber = function(d) {return (d);};` the effect vanishes. Both element move uniformly, although out-of-sync with the background. @Cyril

Comment: @altocumulus I'm wondering if this is the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735424/how-to-animate-a-path-along-with-its-points-in-d3).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I don't think so. That problem was caused by badly synchronized transitions. To avoid the problems associated with that I boiled down the code to just **one** transition with a single tween function returned by `combinedTween()` doing all the transformations at once. I think the problem is somewhere within the calculations along the path using `getTotalLength()` and `getPointAtLength()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Even [more reduced example](http://blockbuilder.org/altocumulus/bede10f6dfc0cbed94e8), still the same issue.

Comment: @altocumulus Yep, definitely those calculations. The same error occurs if you reverse the transition (http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/91bb96d13809df46033f). I'm guessing cumulative rounding errors in `getPointAtLength()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Your assumption is backed by the fact, that this effect shows up in FF 42 and Chrome 46, but not in IE 11. There seem to be differences in the [distance-along-a-path](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#DistanceAlongAPath) implementations across browsers. In fact, all of these browsers print different values for the length of the path and the coordinates of a point at a given length. Then again, these deviations are to small to be the only cause of this effect.

Comment: @altocumulus I've started a community wiki answer for this, feel free to expand that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused not by the transitions getting out of sync, but by the computation of the position of the point on the path. In particular, it occurs in [this reduced example](http://blockbuilder.org/altocumulus/bede10f6dfc0cbed94e8) that doesn't have concurrent transitions and is also visible initially when [the transition is reversed](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/91bb96d13809df46033f).

This effect shows up in FF 42 and Chrome 46, but not in IE 11.